# DRupal and mysql with a remote database

Tags: mysql, drupal

Trying to connect Drupal running from my localhost to a remote database but coming across issues.

I am using the following string in my settings.php file:

$db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/database_name';

I am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\myapp\includes\database.mysqli.inc on line 115

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check connection to remote database:

```
$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306
```

or

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h xx.xx.xx.xx -D database_name
```

On remove server can be configured firewall or MySQL not listen to xx.xx.xx.xx address.

Comment: Thanks. I can successfully connect to the DB on remote host using MySQL Workbench. Only when I am trying to connect with Drupal it doesn't work. Any ideas.

Comment: change "mysqli" to "mysql"

Answer (score 0):

Increase the max execution time in your php.ini to see if this helps.